# How to create image-map in jssor slider

Tags: imagemap, jssor

How to use image-map on jssor. its not working, the link disappears. I have tried the given code.

```
<div id="jssor_4" style="position:relative;margin:0 auto;top:0px;left:0px;width:1500px;height:300px;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;">
    <div data-u="slides" style="cursor:default;position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;width:1500px;height:300px;overflow:hidden;">
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="/images/banner-animasi1.jpg" usemap="#image-map1" style="width:100%" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Bullet Navigator -->
    <div data-u="navigator" class="jssorb108" style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;right:12px;" data-autocenter="1" data-scale="0.5" data-scale-bottom="0.75">
        <div data-u="prototype" class="i" style="width:16px;height:16px;">
            <svg viewbox="0 0 16000 16000" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;">
                <circle class="b" cx="8000" cy="8000" r="5800"></circle>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<map name="image-map1">
    <area target="_self" alt="Tentang kami" title="Tentang kami" href="/about" coords="2666,758,3540,922" shape="rect">
</map>
```

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated. Thanks